# How to clear ALL auto complete suggestions in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I know a similar version of this question exists but my question is: How to clear ***ALL*** auto complete suggestions in Chrome? Not predictions, not auto fill, but auto complete. (Although, I wouldn't mind if the solution requires clearing of those too.) Thank you in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to remove your auto complete in the omnibar.

Example:
[image: Example]
Go to Settings --> Show Advanced --> Clear Browsing Data
[image: Settings]
Clear only History for the beginning of time.
[image: Clear]
Now it only show bookmarks and search results.
[image: Done]